# Manage Shiny Sweetalert Size with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

Below is code showing that the size of a sweetalert when bootstrap is used is very large. If you comment out the `navbarpage()` code chunk I note in the sample below the sweetalert is smaller.

I suppose I could overwrite with new .css which is fine. But, is there an alternative way to deal with that via arguments in the function itself? I don't see an argument in the help, but there is the `...` which passes to .js. I'm not savvy enough with js to know if that's an option and if so what might that look like?

Thanks for any suggestions

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinyBS)


ui <- fluidPage(

    ### Code Chunk to comment out
    navbarPage(
        theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "flatly", version = 4),
        title = 'Methods',
        tabPanel('One'),
    ),
    ### end BS code chunk
    
  tags$h2("Sweet Alert examples"),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "success",
    label = "Launch a success sweet alert",
    icon = icon("check")
  ),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "error",
    label = "Launch an error sweet alert",
    icon = icon("remove")
  ),
  actionButton(
    inputId = "sw_html",
    label = "Sweet alert with HTML",
    icon = icon("thumbs-up")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$success, {
    sendSweetAlert(
      title = "Success !!",
      text = "All in order",
      type = "success"
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$error, {
    sendSweetAlert(
      title = "Error !!",
      text = "It's broken...",
      type = "error"
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$sw_html, {
    sendSweetAlert(
      title = NULL,
      text = tags$span(
        tags$h3("With HTML tags",
                style = "color: steelblue;"),
        "In", tags$b("bold"), "and", tags$em("italic"),
        tags$br(),
        "and",
        tags$br(),
        "line",
        tags$br(),
        "breaks",
        tags$br(),
        "and an icon", icon("thumbs-up")
      ),
      html = TRUE
    )
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Which package does `show_alert` come from?  It doesn't belong any of the packages you loaded on top.

Comment: It should be sendSweetAlert and not show_alert. I edited the post